# Change component color on change of community theme

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, theme-branding

Is there possibility to utilize Communities Themes to change LWC Color (for example button color/svg image color etc)?

Basically I want Community Theme affect custom component.

Answer (score 0):

I can not figure out how to get the communities themes' color infomation via [CommunityThemeDefinition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_communitythemedefinition.htm).

If you can decide which color you want to show according to different themes, you can change the buttons and other components' color you want to change by [Styling Hooks](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/platforms/lightning/styling-hooks/).